# CSS Hover disable on tr:hover

Tags: css, hover, css-tables

I have a table and I have a global css code for tr:hover effect. But sometimes I don't want use this hover effect on my tables. Please look to the code and tell me how do I don't run effect on this table. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bigboytr/LnbUV/). There is a css id here. It's name is product-table. I don't clear this css. IT's rule.

```
#product-table > tbody > tr { cursor:pointer; }
#product-table > tbody > tr:hover { background:#eee; }

.nohover > tbody > tr { cursor:default !important; }
.nohover > tbody > tr:hover { background:inherit !important; }

.green_bg { background-color:#090; }
```

Comment: When and how does it have to be disabled?

Comment: While I mouse over the tr which has green_bg class, background shouldn't be change.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is the Specifity of your css code - [here's a good read about it](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

refering to an element by it's id ( using # ), will always override any style given by referring to it with it's class ( using . ).

In order to override your previous styling, you need to have a specifity level of at least the same.

In your case, you should add the id to the `.nohover` selector to override the previous style.

```
#product-table > tbody > tr { cursor:pointer; }
#product-table > tbody > tr:hover { background:#eee; }

#product-table.nohover > tbody > tr { cursor:default !important; }
#product-table.nohover > tbody > tr:hover { background:#fff !important; }
```

This will override the previous definition because it has an id in it, and a class, which is 1 level higher of just calling it by id.

For a more "official" read, refer to [w3.org's specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)

**EDIT:**

If i have understood correctly, you want to disable all hovering on a table that has a class `.nohover`.

this can be done by applying the hover styles only on tables that don't have the excluding class. like so:

```
#product-table:not(.nohover) > tbody > tr { cursor:pointer; }
#product-table:not(.nohover) > tbody > tr:hover { background:#eee; }

.green_bg { background-color:#090; }
```

Comment: First of all `#product-table.nohover > tbody > tr { cursor:default !important; }
#product-table.nohover > tbody > tr:hover { background:#fff !important; }` this lines didnt work for me. I'm reading article now. And edited my code in first message. .nohover class bg should be inherit. I mean when I mouse over the tr.green_bg, background color shouldn't be change.

Comment: yes It's true. I want to disable all hover effects if element have nohover class. But the point is, if some `<tr>` has green_bg class, this should not be change on mouse over. It's transparent while I mose over now. Please look the JSfiddled in my first message. This will explain better.

Answer (score -1):

Code below for Hover Enable

```
a:hover {

    background-color: yellow;

}
```

---

Code below for Hover Disable

```
a:nohover {

    background-color: yellow;

}
```

Regards,

Satish M Hiremath